# Format Drop Down List in UserForm VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a list in a reference tab of VAT rates shown as 0.0%, 2.0%, 5.0%, 17.5%, 20.0% however when these are added to the userform, they change to the following format: 0.00, 0.02, 0.05, 0.175 and 0.2.

Can anyone advise how I can correct the formatting?

```
#importing the VAT Rate list
NewRangePlan.VATRateDD.List = Ref.Range("AE2:AE7").Value
```

Comment: Use `.Text` instead of `.Value` assuming they are formatted correctly on the worksheet.

Comment: I'm afraid this came back with the error message "Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index.
NewRangePlan.VATRateDD.List = Ref.Range("AE2:AE7").Text

Comment: But `.Value` worked just fine? Then I guess you will have to loop thru them and format them as you go.

Comment: ^ `.Text` doesn't return an array like `.Value` does. Returns `Null` unless each cell in the source range has the same text.

Comment: @BigBen Good to know (why I made it a comment and not an answer, because I've never tried it). I guess I've I always just looped anyways because I will often want multiple columns formatted differently.

Comment: FYI added a short `.List` assignment solution using `MMult()` :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Short `.List` assignment using `MMult()`**

If you can live with a display without the percent sign ("%") in the drop down list, you can try the following approach via WorksheetFunction `MMult()`; otherwise you *"will have to loop thru them and format them as you go"* as mentioned in comment by braX.

```
Dim percents As Range
Set percents = Sheet1.Range("AE2:AE7")  ' set percent data range to memory
Dim factor100 As Range
Set factor100 = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).Resize(1, percents.Rows.Count)
    factor100 = 100                     ' write factor 100 to temporary range
With Me.VATRateDD                       ' assuming DropDown reference within the UserForm code module
    .List = WorksheetFunction.MMult(percents, factor100)
End With
factor100 = vbNullString                ' clear temp range
```

**Further note**

Don't address a form's *default* instance. If you are referring to a control, within the UserForm code module, you may use the `Me` qualifier addressing the form's *current* instance. - *FYI Recommend reading [UserForm1.Show?](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) for a deeper insight.*